1x drive train on older bike
I'm looking for a new drivetrain for an old FS mtb. It's currently a 1x9 but it's still all the old components. All I did was install a new bottom bracket and remove the chainrings and install a 32t narrow wide on the middle of the original crank. I put a new HG-951 chain on but the cassette is still an 11 - 34 t
The parts are 2004 Shimano XT/XTR but even though I cleaned them up and oiled the moving parts, they are showing their use and age. I'm finding pretty good deals on new parts and possibly considering going to a 1x10 or even 1x11. But first I'm looking for some opinions, with experience hopefully, on the pros and cons between Microshift Advent/Advent X, Box 3 Prime 9, and Shimano Deore or the new CUES components. I don't see much from Sram in the sub $200 range so unless you know of anything to include from them, I see no need to include them for this query. Any other brands are welcome for comparison but as stated, I'm looking to stay under $200. I don't need a crank, the one on the bike is good, however I am curious to know if I can convert the bottom bracket to one with the bearings outside the shell for a Hollowtech II crank set. It has the Octa-link now which is similar to the square taper BB-UN300 bottom brackets and I seem to chew those up pretty quickly. That would obviously be separate and not part of the $200 budget for the cassette, derailleur and shifter.
It's just going to be a casual mild trail beater, nothing too complex. I'm most concerned with smooth shifts, reliability/durability, and not having to fiddle with them after initial setup and adjustments.

What is your question?

I ended up sticking with the 1x9 but I have the Microshift Advent shifter and RD with an inexpensive 11 - 48t cassette. The Advent says 46t for largest cog but it works just fine with the 48t with the B screw turned in almost all the way. I had the idea of bypassing 10 & 11 speed altogether and going straight for 12 speed but found out that I would need a new wheel with the Microspline freehub and that would have been costly and not worth it for this bike. I have it all working nicely and it's quite a nice ride for my purpose. Just the Sram Level brakes that are on it are worth $75. I love em!

This close to a shopping recommendation, which is OT for this site. As such I will avoid product recommendations as much as possible.
The main consideration is the BB and crank set. If replacing the crankset, you can, and probably should, move to something with external bearing such as Hollowtech II or equivalent.
As far as the rest goes, if you find 32/11-34 is giving enough range and gap between gears are close enough, then I would suggest sticking with 9 speeds. 9 Speed is less finicky and usually cheaper than 10+, but if it you want more gear range and/or smaller jumps, look to 10 or 11 speed (will depend on relative costs). Cost wise, I don't think there is much benefit going to 12 unless you are going > 42 tooth cassettes.
Product wise, look at cost/benefit. Way I would do this is hit the online retailers and sort by highest discount and see what is around.  The products you are looking at are far enough up the range to give what you are looking for - reliable, no fuss riding.
Make sure you install new cables (inner and outer).

Via shimano, you can get 11-46 rear cassettes (11spd)

Or Microshift's Advent 9s has an 11-46, Advent X 10s has an 11-48. I don't MTB, but 1x 11-34 seems not sufficient?

Advising to stay away from low gear count/large range as the steps between gears get too large. 10s 11-48 is pushing limits of what I consider rideable, but some people have no problem hunting between gears, or slowing down to suit the available gear.
Had a number of questions here regarding this - e.g. https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/56644/difference-between-drivetrains/56647#56647

@mattnz there's a trend in low gear count/large range, that is to go with much less linear gradations, with smaller steps on the smaller sprockets. For example, the 9-speed 11-46 CUES has a combination of 11-13-15-17-20-23-28-36-46 (the difference with 11-36 speed is only on the 3 large sprockets). By contrast, the typical Shimano 11-34 road cassette (11-speed) has 11-13-15-17-19-21-23-25-27-30-34. Considering that people spend most time on small sprockets, I wouldn't have any objection to recommend a "non-linear" 9-speed 11-48.

I'm running the 9 speed 11 - 48t with no issues. I'm 5'8" around 160 lbs so not a big guy and the shift points and gear ratios are quite easy to handle, up hill, tight trails, rough terrain, no issues. I find it quite a nice set up.
